# Cassandra Latitude Longitude Lookup Table

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, latitude-longitude, cql

I need to make a lookup table which returns the location info when I provide Latitude and Longitude. We are already using Cassandra database for our application.

1. Latitude (partition key)
2. Longitude (clustering key)
3. Location info

My doubt is that is it good to make above design. Latitude and Longitude are high cardinality data. I don't need any range queries on Latitude and Longitude.

Or should I go for Mongodb and geospatial index ?

I am a beginner in database design, I don't know if lookup speed will reduce if data is growing bigger in the above table.

Comment: if you are always going to use latitude and longitude in your query then create partition key as `(latitiude,longitude)`... no clustering key reqd

Comment: Will the speed of lookup will reduce when the data is growing large size ?

Comment: with the above partition key, it will not reduce.... i.e for query `SELECT loc_info from table where latitude='SOMEVALUE' and longitude='SOMEVALUE'`... for this kind of query performance will not degrade irrespective of data